# IngredientName and Measurement

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to run this query:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS('-',i.IngredientName,p.Measurement) SEPARATOR ' ; ' ) IngredientName, p.Measurement
FROM tbl_ingredient i, tbl_post p
WHERE FIND_IN_SET( i.IngredientID, p.IngredientIDs )
GROUP BY p.PostID
```

Sample Output:

```
IngredientName                               |            Measurement
---------------------------------------------+----------------------------
Lime Juice-1 oz                              |              1 oz
Lime Juice-1 oz,2 oz ; Lemon Juice-1 oz,2 oz |             1 oz,2 oz
```

Desired output:

```
IngredientName                               |            Measurement
---------------------------------------------+----------------------------
Lime Juice-1 oz                              |              1 oz
Lime Juice-1 oz ; Lemon Juice-2 oz           |             1 oz,2 oz
```

Measurement must be according to IngredientName.

Comment: solved by normalizing the database..

Answer (score 0):

Problem has been solved by normalizing my database.